# How to write the same code using pipes in R?

Tags: r, pipe

I'm very new to R and can't get a hold of using pipes for trivial commands. How to write these correctly working commands using pipes instead? The following two problems are not related.
1) I'm trying to remove duplicates from my dataframe and replace the old dataframe with a new one that has no duplicated values. 
2) I'm trying to change factor format to date format.

1) `df <- df[!duplicated(df),]`

2) `df$date_col <- anytime(df$date_col, 
        useR = getOption("anytimeUseRConversions", FALSE), 
        oldHeuristic = getOption("anytimeOldHeuristic", FALSE))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
df %>%
     distinct() %>%
     mutate(date_col = anytime(date_col))
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I'm sorry I did not previously clarify my question to the fullest - I've now edited it. 
From your code I understood that removing duplicates and updating the dataframe with new without-duplicates-dataframe, i can do the following:
**df <- df %>%
distinct()**
However, i also tried the following
**df <- df %>% 
!duplicated()**
And here I get an error message : _Error in duplicated.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default_

So how would you write my problem #1 using pipes and the command **duplicated** ?